# Numerical operations when numbers are very large?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, floating-point

Explain the best way to evaluate $f(x,y) = \sqrt{(x^2 + y^2)}$ numerically when $x$ or $y$ are very large.

Does anyone have any insight to this? I'm lost. I usually know how to deal with these types of questions when it involves small numbers but no idea how to go about this.

Comment: if $x>>y$, it's $x + y^2/(2 x) - y^4/(8 x^3) + O((1/x)^4)$

Comment: Actually, very small numbers give similar problems too. You need to normalise the numbers into medium size numbers before you do the calculations: see kpres's and my answers.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: I suspect the OP is after some more specific help in how to go about the calculation using floating-point number representations.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if $x$ and $y$ are very large (and positive)? The only possible problem is floating point overflow, to avoid that you would compute $\max(x,y)\sqrt{1+(\min(x,y)/\max(x,y))^2}$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner : Your calculation shows that there is no problem in that kind of size difference. The original formula loses any influence of $y$ when $|y|<\sqrt{\mu}|x|$, $\mu$ the floating point machine constant. The first two terms of your formula (and the result of the original formula) loses any influence of $y$ when $|y|<\sqrt{2\mu}|x|$. This means that you gain nothing with such a case distinction.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: I have no idea what you mean by "the floating point machine constant" or by "gain nothing with such a case distinction". If you need to carry out the computation using standard floating point arithmetic, then there **is** a problem if $x$ or $y$ is so large that calculating $x^2$ or $y^2$ would overflow. This problem can be solved - see my answer to the question (and note that it involves no case disitinctions other than which of $x$ and $y$ has the larger absolute value).

Answer (score 3):

For the purposes of my example, I'm going to assume that both of your numbers are in the range of $10^{12}$. If you have $6*10^{12}$ for $x$ and $8*10^{12}$ for $y$, then you can factor out $10^{12}$ and end up with $$\sqrt{(10^{12})^2*(6^2+8^2)}.$$

This becomes $$\sqrt{6^2+8^2}*10^{12}.$$

If they are both large numbers, but very far apart in magnitude, then for all practical purposes you are going to get a number that's very close to the larger number and the smaller one might not even make it into your significant figures.

Comment: It might be useful to provide some asymptotics for the case in your last paragraph, as in J.W. Tanner's comment to the OP.  (I haven't checked his asymptotic for accuracy, but that's the sort of thing that might be useful.)

Comment: Very nice take! Seems like you are saying that instead of performing the operation of $10^{12}$ itself we can factor out the order of magnitude and evaluate the smaller numbers themselves in usual fashion. This makes a lot of sense thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps, here is something like the idea behind kpres's answer turned into python code:

```
import math
def sqrt_sq_plus_sq(x, y):
   if abs(x) < abs(y): # swap x and y if necessary so that abs(x) >= abs(y)
      return sqrt_sq_plus_sq(y, x)
   (mx, ex) = math.frexp(x) # x = mx * 2**ex with 0 <= abs(mx) <= 1
   (my, ey) = math.frexp(y) # y = my * 2**ey with 0 <= abs(my) <= 1
   ny = my * (2**(ey - ex)) # y = ny * 2**ex
   return (2**ex) * math.sqrt(mx*mx + ny*ny)
      # return value is 2**ex * sqrt(mx^2 + ny^2) = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
```

The python function math.frexp gives the (base 2) mantissa and exponent of a floating point number.

The idea is to scale the numbers up or down so that the mantissas are in the interval $[0, 1]$, do the calculation and then scale up or down to the right exponent. (Note that very small $x$ and $y$ are just as problematic as very large ones.)

Here are a couple of test runs:

```
>>> sqrt_sq_plus_sq(3e100,-4e100)
5e+100
>>> sqrt_sq_plus_sq(-5e-100, 12e-100)
1.3e-99
```

Comment: Very nice example and thank you for providing the code! So what I'm taking from this is essentially to scale the numbers down for the calculation and then scale them back up afterwards

Comment: @APMATH24 This answer helps you deal with floating point overflow or underflow. Do you have either of those problems? If not, this kind of thing is probably not helpful.

Comment: @DavidK: No. This is *the* answer to this problem. Lutz Lehmann's comment is the standard LAPACK answer due to Sven Hammarling, see subroutine xnrm2. Rob Arthan's manipulation of the exponent is *the* solution used by those of us who need to write code which cannot fail due to overflow/underflow and is easy to prove correct.

Comment: @CarlChristian You're probably right, but OP could settle it just by saying "yes".